# how is useful to use IsAsync in the binding of a combobox?

Tags: wpf

When I set the items source of a combobox, I have the option to se IsAsync as true.

When is it useful to use this parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: It might be useful when building the source collection takes a long time. Do you have a specific usage scenario?

Comment: Not really, I just wondering when it could be useful, because I have tried to set true and false and I didn't see any difference. In my case the source doesn't take many time.

Comment: Take a look at its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.isasync?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). The use case seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

`IsAsync` is most useful for properties whose values take take a long time to retrieve or set via binding.  It can make your application remain responsive while the bound value is being retrieved/set.  For values that are retrieved immediately, it is not at all useful.

Does your checkbox-bound value take a long time to retrieve/set its values?  If not, then `IsAsync` is a waste.

I will admit I've never used `IsAsync` with a two-way binding.  Usually I save it for read-only properties